# operand of LIDT is displacement/absolute address

Tags: linux, x86, intel, linux-device-driver, x86-64

I stumbled upon a statement in Intel Software developers manual:
"For LGDT, LIDT, LLDT, LTR, SGDT, SIDT, SLDT, STR, the exit qualification receives the value of the instruction’s displacement field, which is sign-extended to 64 bits if necessary (32 bits on processors that do not support Intel 64 architecture). If the instruction has no displacement (for example, has a register operand), zero is stored into the exit qualification. "

Now if I have an instruction LIDT 0xf290, then is "0xf290" a displacement? I think answer is yes.

So, my confusion is what all constitute as displacement? I was under impression that displacement is something which is calculated with respect to current eip value. 
For eg. jmp xxx (In intrasegment jumps this will be a displacement. But for intersegment jumps, it should be absolute address.) If that is the case then why LIDT loads a relative address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *displacement* is just an offset from some origin, which may be a `Base+Index*Scale`, or 0. The other operand x86 has that can hold large values is *immediate*, which is useful for things like adding constants (e.g. `ADD $42, %eax`).

Incidentally, it appears that relative jumps use the *immediate* field, probably because they modify `EIP` by a constant.

Comment: it sounds weird to have a relative address for lidt. If i write some code as follows:                                                  uint64 lidt_val =get_idt_val_asm_func();   //sidt asm func                                lot_of_c_code_in_between_.......                                       set_idt_val_asm_func(lidt_val)   //lidt asm func                                    Now if we consider a relative address is used to set lidt then sidt will return some address which will be an absolute val in idt. But lidt will use it as a relative val. which is not correct.

Comment: @agent: _displacements_ represent memory addresses, whether relative or absolute (origin 0), while _immediates_ represent integer constants.